# Mid 2010 15" MacBook Pro, have had the dGPU disabled before, have now replaced the logic board completely; How do I re-enable the dGPU

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, gpu

I have a Mid 2010 MPB 15". When the Logic Board failed due to the dGPU kernel panic, I had a tech install a program to remove or disable the dGPU. Since then I have now replaced the logic board completely with a repaired used logic board. Everything works well, I would like to use the now repaired dGPU, but I do not know how to get it to work. I am not the most savvy with programs, software or code, I can follow clear instructions well. If anyone knows what to do and could guide me, that would be incredibly appreciated.

Here are some specs.
Mid 2010 MacBook Pro 15"
High Sierra 10.13.6
Model Identifier: MacBookPro6,2
Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
Processor Speed:  2.66 GHz
Number of Processors: 1
Total Number of Cores:    2
L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
L3 Cache: 4 MB
Memory:   4 GB
Boot ROM Version: 96.0.0.0.0
SMC Version (system): 1.58f17

If any more details are needed, i am happy to answer.

Comment: “A tech installed a program” is quite broad for us to work with.  Have you tried contacting that tech?  Why not get an SSD and do a clean install of High Sierra on that - the GPU will be (re)enabled natively.

Comment: A search for how to disable GPU on 2010 MBP should turn up the various methods, so you can then see how to dis-disable it.